# What's the right way to read Princeton companion to mathematics?(for non-mathematician)

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

I am thinking of ways,how one(who is not a mathematician, but wants to know what's going on in the field of mathematics) can properly read Princeton companion to mathematics to make sense of it. I think first one should read part 3(which has mathematical concepts,which are briefly discussed in part 1 and 2),then part 2 and part 1 and then part 5(which has theorems and problems which are discussed briefly in part 4) and then part 4 and then parts 7,8 and 9 cover to cover. I think that's the right way to read this book.

Any suggestions?(I may be completely wrong)

Comment: What do you mean by not a mathematician? There's a spectrum. Do you know what quantifiers mean? Can you read a mathematical sentence with 3 alternations of quantifiers? The definition of continuity is a classic example.

Comment: By non-mathematician I mean someone who knows only high school math. And I don't know what you mean by quantifiers.

Comment: Then I encourage you to start at the beginning. There is a lot of technical terminology that will go over your head if you've never seen it before. Reading math is a lot of fun. But it's also slow sometimes. Math has its own technical grammar, and there's no substitute for learning the fundamentals. Leaning the fundamentals well lets you get to all kinds of crazy and interesting stuff. I also encourage you to post questions on this site as you read through it.

Comment: I tried reading from beginning but I encountered these problems - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424182/is-there-better-alternative-to-princeton-companion-to-mathematics-because-i-can ,so that's why I am thinking of an alternative way to read this book.

Comment: (FYI, linking to related questions in your  original post is always helpful.) I think the people in that thread already answered your question, it's just not the answer you were hoping for. The book looks like it's intended to accompany undergraduates taking other math courses. It's doesn't look like a great resource on its own. I'm sure somewhere on MSE is a link to something better for self study. You're gonna have to learn fundamentals somewhere. Finding the right resource is more than half that battle.

Comment: Read it in whatever order you think is reasonable, then read it again.